# Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'&' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'

Tags: xml, powershell, unexpected-token

I have PS script that connects to a XML file.
However i get this error duo to specific a line in my XML file:

Error message: Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "'&' is an unexpected token. The expected token is ';'Line 22, position 99."

This is line 22:

```
<Option Name="Action" Value="https://website.com/&sys_id=a3f50914db194450165992b8db96192d" />
```

I've edited the website link as i cannot share this.

The last part of the value is what triggers the error starting at "&"

The error appears to be at "&" which is pos 99 in line 22.
I tried to remove that and run it again. Then the error appears at "_" removing that it happens for "=".
Seems like it doesn't like these special characters.

The idea is to have a button that takes you to a specific site. If i just had https://website.com then it would work but i will need it to go deeper than just to the basic frontpage.

I reckon it must be something in the PS script that needs to be modified but haven't been able to figure out what.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like someone forgot to properly escape their data before serializing it :) correct escape sequence for `&` in a string would be `&amp;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to escape special characters. Here is a reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-use-special-characters-in-xaml

Try this instead:

```
<Option Name="Action" Value="https://website.com/&amp;sys_id=a3f50914db194450165992b8db96192d" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! My script is still not working but it doesn't get the unexpected token error anymore so at least in the right direction :-)